# k8s access api from application in pod over subdomain via service

Tags: kubernetes, cluster-computing, rancher

I would like to access my pods created by my backend via subdomain, i already setup a pod yaml and a service yaml

I followed the official k8s docs but its not working, i just get connection refused when i visit http://playout-6297bbdceab3f039170509ee.default-subdomain.default.svc.domain.com

Here are both yaml files:

Service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: default-subdomain
spec:
  selector:
    name: playout
  clusterIP: None
  ports:
  - name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 7999
```

Pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: playout-6297bbd9eab3f039170509e8
  namespace: default
  labels:
    name: playout
spec:
  hostname: playout-6297bbd9eab3f039170509e8
  subdomain: default-subdomain
  containers:
    - image: eli4n/playout:playout-latest
      ports:
        - containerPort: 7999
      env:
        - name: PLAYOUT_STATION
          value: 6297bbceeab3f039170509df
        - name: PLAYOUT_CHANNEL
          value: 6297bbd9eab3f039170509e8
      name: playout
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: regcred`
```

I use k8s with rancher via hetzner cloud driver

Btw i'm really new to k8s

Thanks!

Comment: Please share the documentation you followed with us so we can fully understand what you trying to accomplish

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/